# How to Increase Axis: Pandas: ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 1 elements, new values have 30 elements

Tags: python, pandas

How do I increase my axis to have 30 elements? I am facing this error

```
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 1 elements, new values have 30 elements
```

Listed below is my code

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
for chunk in pd.read_csv('verybig.csv', sep='|', header=None, chunksize=1000, low_memory=False):
    df = pd.concat([df, chunk], ignore_index=True)

df.columns = ['MyTime','Attribute','Court','Energy','State','30','29','28','27','26','25','24','23','22','21','20','19','18','17','16','15','14','13','12','11','10','9','8','7','6']
```

I would like to note that verybig.csv is around 1GB

UPDATE: After executing df.head(5) I see the following

```
>>> df.head(5)
                                               0
0  2018-09-01 00:00:03,262, aid:Ut7XsnHXaqf6p4Pyc...
1  2018-09-01 00:00:16,966, aid:kzhUOAJRHxfgwKdmy...
2  2018-09-01 00:00:19,008, aid:QeKRGSs4QRP-f8dIZ...
3  2018-09-01 00:00:19,202, aid:ScGESqQOEY6YkrGoY...
4  2018-09-01 00:00:24,799, aid:Hajk1NF0tIIVELz2N...
>>>
```

UPDATE 2: I think the path way to my solution is to split the above column (Column 0) using the comma as the separator after the following code is executed

```
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    for chunk in pd.read_csv('verybig.csv', sep='|', header=None, chunksize=1000, low_memory=False):
        df = pd.concat([df, chunk], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: its seems like you have a length mismatch between your data frame and the amount of column names you want to set.

Comment: can you do df.head(5) an include the results?

Comment: Seems you got the `sep` argument wrong and verybig.csv is computing just one column. If you print your dataframe's .head() as Yuca suggested we might help you better.

Comment: df.head(5) detail added

Answer (score 0):

If you see in your `df.head()`, your DataFrame has just one column. Also you can see the separator is ',' instead of '|'. You can try the following:

```
df=pd.read_csv('verybig.csv', sep=',', header=None, chunksize=1000, low_memory=False)
df.columns = ['MyTime','Attribute','Court','Energy','State','30','29','28','27','26','25','24','23','22','21','20','19','18','17','16','15','14','13','12','11','10','9','8','7','6']
```

Does that work for you?

Comment: It didn't work but I think I found the pathway to the solution. See my question's latest edit